# Low performance composer with docker for Symfony 3.4

Tags: performance, docker, composer-php, freeze, symfony-3.4

I work with Docker for all my projects, however I have a problem with Symfony 3.4 and Composer with Docker .

When I add some more packages, Composer freezes on update and I need to restart Docker to unblock the situation.

I have no idea whether the problem comes from Symfony or Composer.

I think it's comes from Symfony because when I try with Symfony 4.3 there are no problems.

Can you help me to find a clue to resolve this problem?

Generally, I launch Composer with the following command line:

```
docker run --rm --name composer -ti -w /var/www -v %cd%:/var/www composer ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve my problem,

set 4G RAM for Docker and it work.